Video control with encoder on Raspberry pi 5, MPV and Python
Controls made with MPV and 4 video buttons in Python, forward and rewind operation with rotary encoder
In the normal flow of the video, the rewinding process should be slow, that is, the encoder should play the stopped video. I am doing this project using Raspberry Pi 5. Can this project be done with the materials I use? If so, what steps should I follow?
What path should I follow?
